# Highstock padding/margin with range selector

Tags: highcharts

For the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kami924/cpvLzLso/33/),I want to use the rangeSelector (but do not want to show them on chart) because I want the chart always show the data for 3 months, which means I cannot disable the range selector.

To hide the range selector I have used:

```
buttonTheme: {
                visibility: 'hidden'
            },
labelStyle: {
                visibility: 'hidden'
            }
```

Now on top of chart there is a space/blank area. I want to hide it. The reason is I want to show the chart in a small box. And this blank area because of range selector looks awkward in layout. I am thinking is there a way to add negative margin below range selector buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set chart's margin, spacing top to negative value.

```
chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        spacingTop: 0,
        marginTop: -35
    },
```

Or better, set the range selector's height to 0.

```
rangeSelector: {
        height: 0,
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/cpvLzLso/34/

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of the height parameter for rangeSelector. My rangeSelector didn't show up at all, until I discovered that a height of e.g. 100 has to be set.